# Measuring page load time in the footer

Tags: zend-framework, geolocation, benchmarking, footer

In my Zend Framework app, I have following code:

index.php

```
$app_started_time = time();
```

layout.phtml

```
$elapsed = time() - $app_started_time;
```

Does users internet speed and geo location have an impact of $elapsed value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No
Because what you are measuring above is server processing elapsed time .Its independent of user .